# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \vert \cos \pi e^{i\theta}\vert d \theta$ using complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the value$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln | \cos \pi e^{i\theta}\vert d \theta$ for the entire function $\cos z$ (Here the $\ln$ is natural logarithm )

I put the $z = e^{i\theta}$, then we have $dz= iz d\theta$. Therefore, $$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \vert \cos \pi e^{i\theta}\vert d \theta = \int_{\vert z \vert =1} \frac{\ln\vert \cos \pi z\vert}{iz} dz$$

Therefore isolated singularities are $z=0, \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2}$. say $g(z) = \frac{\ln\vert \cos \pi z\vert}{iz}$

For the $z=0$ case, $\operatorname{res}(g,0) = 0$ [simple pole].

But I'm stuck for solving the other cases $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2}$.
How can I integrate that?

Answer (score 1):

$z\to\cos(\pi z)$ maps the unit circle into a sort of cardioid $\gamma$ where the distance from the origin is always $\geq 1$, since $\left|\,\cos(\pi e^{i\theta})\,\right|^2 = \cos^2(\pi\cos\theta) 
  +\sinh^2(\pi\sin\theta) $. Then

$$ \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\ln\left|\cos(\pi z)\right|}{iz}\,dz = \text{Re}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\ln\cos(\pi z)}{iz}\,dz=\text{Im}\oint_{|z|=1}\ln(\cos(\pi z))\frac{dz}{z}.\tag{1}$$

From the Weierstrass product for the cosine function
$$ \cos(\pi z) = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right) \tag{2}$$

hence for a suitable determination of $\ln$ the outcome is the same as
$$ \text{Im}\oint_{|z|=1}\ln(1-4z^2)\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(4-e^{-2i\theta})\,d\theta = \color{red}{4\pi \log 2}. \tag{3} $$

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your answer. :) But I can't understand the part (3). Firstly, From the $(2)$, Would you more explain more specifically to get the  $Im\int ln(1-4z^2)$? Secondly,  Why is  $Im\int ln(1-4z^2) \frac{dz}{z}$ same as  $\int ln (4-e^{-2i\theta})$? Finally, How you got the answer from the  $\int ln (4-e^{-2i\theta})$?